# Cron file - disable access (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, yaml

I'm running a cron file in Google App Engine. It seems to be working fine, except I don't want anyone to be able to access the URL.

Here is my .cron file:

```
cron:
- description: testing cron
url: /tester
schedule: every 1 minutes
```

I tried adding: "login: admin" underneath "schedule", but I get:

```
enter code here
Error parsing yaml file:
Unexpected attribute 'login' for object of type <class 'google.appengine.api.croninfo.CronEntry'>.
```

So how do I prevent someone from calling the url and running a script that should be automated?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You restrict access to URLs in app.yaml. Add a correspondent entry for your cron tester:

```
application: hello-cron
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /tester
  script: tester.py
  login: admin
```

Comment: Ah, I read that as if it were the cron file. Works now, thanks

Comment: @Petwoip i am facing the same issue, my code is in nodejs and i have mentioned script :ignored in app.yaml as i don't have any python script to run. I have handled the route in node js using 'app.get('/tasks', function())'

Comment: read the doc indeed this might be the reason. _The login setting is available only when using a compat runtime in Python, Java, or Go._. [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml]